# Bitnami. reset mysql root pwd

Tags: mysql, bitnami

How do I reset the root pwd and account in MySQL as I was following instructions how to grant priveledges for other servers and accidently tied root user (Mysql) to other ip address and now it seems that I can not log in as admin on localhost?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have 3 ways to reset rootpass in mysql:**

**1** - launch the following command:

`sudo service mysql reset-password`

---

**2** - You can also try:

```
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-x.x`
```

---

**3** - The third solution is a bit longer but worked for me:

```
`sudo service mysql stop`

`sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & mysql -h localhost`
```

You're now connected to mysql bypassing privileges.

```
USE mysql;

UPDATE USER
SET    password = password('<your_new_pass>')
WHERE  USER = 'root' AND host = 'localhost';
```

Your root pass should be resetted now. just quit mysql clt and restart mysql service:

```
quit

sudo mysqladmin shutdown

sudo service mysql start
```