# Bitnami server: Reset the MySQL root password

Tags: mysql, linux, bitnami

I don’t remember my MySQL root password used in 'Bitnami WordPress Stack' (wordpress-5.4.2-0) in Linuy-Mint and tried the steps described here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/administration/change-reset-password/

explicitly:

`nano installdir/mysql/tmp/mysql-init`

and saved it with:

`ALTER USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'NEW_PASSWORD';`

then i restarted the MySQL server via Bitname App **installdir/manager-linux-x64.run**

i expected to be able in:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php

with user root and NEW_PASSWORD but get then this error-message:

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This way is different to suggestions on: [Bitnami. reset mysql root pwd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061869/bitnami-reset-mysql-root-pwd)

i tried also:

```
~/wordpress-5.4.2-0/mysql$ service mysql reset-password
mysql: unrecognized service
```

~/wordpress-5.4.2-0/mysql$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-x.x

and get the same errors in phpmyadmin.

if i use:

`sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & mysql -h localhost`

it got

`Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed`

but of course its installed.

Comment: workaround: i made a backup and installed again 'Bitnami WordPress Stack' from https://bitnami.com/download/files/stacks/wordpress/5.4.2-1/bitnami-wordpress-5.4.2-1-linux-x64-installer.run?with_popup_skip_signin=1